# JsonString to Object in VB6

Tags: json, vb6

So I need to convert following response from Httprequest of JsonString to Object. Can someone help in looping it to an object. [New to Vb6]

Please see the below Json response.

```json
{
    "Participants": [
    {
      "Participant": {
        "EntityHierarchy": {},
        "ProviderPlatform": "string",
        "ProviderPlatformDetail": [
          {
            "ProviderPlatform": "string",
            "Primary": true
          }
        ],
        "FirstName": "string",
        "LastName": "string",
        "BusinessName": "string",
        "City": "string",
        "Region": "string",
        "PostalCode": "string",
        "Phone": "string",
        "CountryCode": "string",
        "Email": "string",
        "AccountNumber": "string",
        "Active": true,
        "PSuiteAttribute": "string",
        "ParticipantIdentifier": "string",
        "SystemParticipantIdentifier": "string",
        "ITAIdentifier": "string"
        },
       "Platform": "string",
       "Program": "string",
       "ProgramFriendlyName": "string",
       "EnterpriseServicesIdentifier": "string",
       "IdentityMapped": true,
       "MappedToMasterPlatform": true,
       "MasterPlatform": "string",
       "SupportingPlatform": "string",
       "MasterPlatformName": "string",
       "SupportingPlatformName": "string",
       "FaultedMessages": [
       "string"
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bruce McPherson makes heavy use of a class called `cJobject` to do JSON handling in VBA/VB6. `cJobject` is too big to fit in an answer, but you can get its current source code [off GitHub](https://github.com/brucemcpherson/cJobject). See also his [usage notes](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json/howcjobject).

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of JSON classes floating around written in VB6, VBA, or VB6 that is portable to VBA.

Here are a couple more:

[JsonBag, Another JSON Parser/Generator](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738845-VB6-JsonBag-Another-JSON-Parser-Generator)

[JNode - JSON revisited](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?807029-VB6-JNode-JSON-revisited)